# Swift 2.0 API Call

Tags: ios, swift

I wrote an iOS app in swift, and had to convert it to 2.0 to put it on the app store. The app was working fine before, but had some migration issues with a JSON API call. I added in a catch statement, but I still keep getting errors. Right now it is saying i'm missing an expression at the end, nothing very descriptive. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
let url : String = "http://xproshowcasex.api.channel.livestream.com/2.0/livestatus.json"
    let request : NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest()
    request.URL = NSURL(string: url)
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

    NSURLSession.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue(), completionHandler:{ (response:NSURLResponse?, data: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        let jsonResult: AnyObject?
        do {
            jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: [])
            print(jsonResult, terminator: "");
            let channel: NSDictionary! = jsonResult!.valueForKey("channel") as! NSDictionary;
            print(channel, terminator: "");
            let result: NSNumber! = channel.valueForKey("isLive") as! NSNumber;
            print(result, terminator: "");

            if (result == 0)
            {
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "", message:
                    "There is no live stream right now", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,handler: nil))

                self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }

        }
         catch
         {
            // TODO: handle
        }
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know where `sendAsynchronousRequest` is defined for `NSURLSession`, so I can't check the method signature to make sure you are using it correctly, but to start you have a bracket in the wrong spot towards the end.

For what it is worth, in the future, that sort of "expected expression" error is a syntax error and points to something that you didn't type the way the compiler expected. In those cases, double check things like braces and parentheses and other common areas of syntax confusion.

```
let url : String = "http://xproshowcasex.api.channel.livestream.com/2.0/livestatus.json"
let request : NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest()
request.URL = NSURL(string: url)
request.HTTPMethod = "GET"


NSURLSession.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue(), completionHandler:{ (response:NSURLResponse?, data: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

    let jsonResult: AnyObject?
    do {
        jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: [])
        print(jsonResult, terminator: "");
        let channel: NSDictionary! = jsonResult!.valueForKey("channel") as! NSDictionary;
        print(channel, terminator: "");
        let result: NSNumber! = channel.valueForKey("isLive") as! NSNumber;
        print(result, terminator: "");

        if (result == 0)
        {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "There is no live stream right now", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,handler: nil))

            self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    }
    catch
    {
        // TODO: handle
    }
})
```

Comment: Ah ok, thank you. I'm now getting the error `type 'NSURLSession' has no member 'sendAsynchrounousequest'`

Comment: Yes, as I stated, I don't know where you are getting that function from. It's not part of the standard `NSURLSession` API, so perhaps it was added in an extension or category somewhere? I don't know, you'll have to look back at how that call got there in the first place.

Comment: Ah ok. Would you reccomend using something instead of `sendAsynchrounousequest `?

Comment: NSURLSession is a fine choice, you just have to use it differently. If you want something a bit more user friendly, then you can check out the AlamoFire library, but you'll need some experience in integrating a third party framework.

Comment: Check out `NSURLSession`s `dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:` method.

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace your

```
NSURLSession.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue(), completionHandler:{ (response:NSURLResponse?, data: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
```

with

```
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

        }
```

Comment: Cool, that fixed my other issue. Thank you!